# SSIS Data Transfer says nnnn rows copied, but count on table is less?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a controlling package to manage data transfers between two different data sources, so we can coy multiple tables and capture how many rows were transferred and duration for each transfer.
[image: Process view]

The package was working as intended until yesterday, when I promoted a change to the controlling package to allow us to have variables which determine whether the transfer required the destination table to be Truncated or not. The next day I saw the bizarre behaviour of the Package log stating all rows transferred, but the actual table counts were not what the log stated, see attached file. Thinking, as usual that it may be something my change did, I reverted the change and guess what the same errors happened, but on some of the same tables and some different ones. 
As it is the child packages doing the transfers and nothing has changed in them, has anyone got any ideas how this could possibly happen? We did have a SAN controller fail a week or so ago and we are now back on that same controller, but either way I cannot see how the log would be able to say all rows are transferred and yet not all of the rows are actually moved???

If you need anything further please let me know as this has me well and truly baffled...

- [Process output - where you can see counts and log](http://www.learningthroughplay.net/datax/Table%20Transfers%20DEV.xlsx)
- [Table Transfer Controller (as txt not dtsx)](http://www.learningthroughplay.net/datax/Table_Transfers.txt)
- [An example of the data transfer child packages (as txt not dtsx)](http://www.learningthroughplay.net/datax/PolicyGenericTransactionItem.txt)

regards,

Anthony

Comment: It looks as though switching back to the second SAN controller has done the trick, I haven't got a clue why or how the row counts could not match...

Comment: The problem came back today and we 're on the same controller????